# req.body is undefined, but body-parser is initialized

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

All the time I get an error calling req.body is undefined, but I included body-parser in my middlewares.
I use it like it should be used, at least I think I do because I get the warning

> 'body-parser' is deprecated

Is it correct initialization of body-parser? Why do I get that error?

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

EDIT

I just added bodyParser to my route middleware, and now it works. Can someone explain why it work only that way, when none of tutorials do it like this?

doesn't work:

```
app.use('/api/users', authRoute)
```

works

```
app.use('/api/users', bodyParser.json(), authRoute)
```

EDIT2

It was because I defined middlewares below route middlewares, I didn't know order matters, maybe not only me so I leave this edit

Comment: do you have proper header indicate it's a json?

Comment: yes, headers are set to application/json in my postman app

Comment: Is the `app.use(bodyParser.json())` line *above* the route where you're checking `req.body`? Because with express, order matters. You need to set up middleware  before your routes, or it won't run unless you call it manually like in your edit example.

Comment: oh, it was below, didn't know that order matters, thanks

Comment: If you have found the answer, I would recommend leaving the edit out and adding an answer to your own question (and marking it as such) - that way, people can see that a given question indeed has an answer.  Otherwise, it will remain 'unanswered' to the system and to those who do not read the entire question as they will not realize that the answer is added as an edit to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was I defined middlewares below route middlewares, I didn't know order matters, maybe not only me so I leave this solution for someone who's going to get this problem in a future

Answer (score 1):

This answer really helped me! Thanks. I was doing the same mistake of defining my middlewares below my routes, also one thing in `"^express version 4.17.1"` instead of `app.use(bodyParser.json());`, we could also use `app.use(express.json());` and it also works fine, may be this version of express has inbuilt support for `JSON`.

Comment: As far as I know express.json() was deprecated

Comment: May be the case with previous version but If you check the  latest documentation of the `express`, you will see it is clearly mentioned over there.